# DataGridView обращение к столбцу и строке (ячейке)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть 2 формы

1 форма - водим в `TextBox` ФИО и телефон, также путем расчета в один из `Label` выводится сумма к оплате

2 форма - подвешен компонент `DatаGridView`

Вопрос: как в `DatаGridView` путем обращения добавить данные из `TextBox(ов)` и `Label(ов)`?

По возможности в следующем порядке - Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, Телефон, Сумма(заказа).

```
n = Sell.dataGridView1.RowCount;
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    label14.Text = ysl.dataGridView2.Rows[n].Cells[n].Value; // = sum;
sum = label14.Text
Sell.table1TableAdapter.Insert(n + 1, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, label14.Text); // textBox.Text);
```

Вот такой набросок с учетом добавления на форму `ComboBox` (но речь сейчас не об этом).

Помогите примером пожалуйста.

Comment: Как присвоить значение ячейки к переменной,
Хочу присвоить к типу int,
Пишет ошибку,
То что тип должен быть object,
Хотя ячейка хранит целочисленный тип

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то вам нужно создать `public` метод, которым можно добавлять записи в `dataGridView`, и экземпляр класса, в котором содержится `dataGridView` передавать с конструктором в класс, в котором вы вводите значения, ну и после подтверждения ввода данных вызывайте этот метод и передавайте параметрами - данные для добавления. Таким образом вы передадите данные в правильною форму.

На счет `object`. Ячейка возвращает `object`, но с помощью функции `.ToString()` вы можете получить стринговое значение, после чего можно приводить к любому типу, например

`int.Parse(x[x,y].ToString());`

Ещё советую добавить оглавление в `dataGridView` в свойствах, или же программным путем.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь